# Previewg images via IKImage View

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsfilemanager, ikimageview

I need help ,I am pressed by time and I am blocked. Ihave a table view containing a directory's files (icon, name, size, date) . Tha table is filled via an arraycontroller. The table view just displays the image files and pdf files.When I select a row I want to preview the content in an IKImage view which isjust under the table. But I can't preview the content. Can you help me and give me some documentation , tutorials or commands on how to preview them and how to use ikimage view? I guess the ikimage view is the best solution. What do you think about that?

Comment: hello every body! why don't you answer , we are here to help eachh other

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have come up with the solution but a referral for others who might come here.
 
 read [apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageKitProgrammingGuide/ImageViews/ImageViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004907-CH4-SW9) 
its simple to start with.
  In your case you can use 
 `- (void)setImage:(CGImageRef)image imageProperties:(NSDictionary *)metaData` 
 where your file properties can go in as dictionary object. 
   In the apple's example you can check out how to get CGImageRef from filepath, or you can use `setImageWithURL`.